# Permanently update variable name (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to Java programming and I am currently completing the University of Helsinki's MOOC Java programming course. I am not sure what I have done, but I seem to have permanently updated the Scanner variable to be just "Scanner scan". Originally, this was set to "Scanner scanner", but this is no longer the case. Each time I open one of the TMC exercises, I have to now manually update the variable to be "Scanner scanner".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Write your program here 
    }
```

This isn't causing too much of an issue and is more of a cosmetic thing, but I wondered if anyone was able to advise how I could permanently update this so it is set to Scanner scanner by default again? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "permanently"?

Comment: You can rename the variable using the "rename" item in the refactoring menu (shift-f6?)

Comment: Not sure what is the problem about.